# Lower accuracy with a larger testing set

Tags: cross-validation, svm

I'm new in this forum and I want to ask a question: I'm working with SVM and I want to choose the best parameters for my model so I do as follows:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:,:2]
y = iris.target
X_trainval,X_test,y_trainval,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid=train_test_split(X_trainval,y_trainval, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
Cs=[0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]
gammas=[0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]
best_score=0
C_best=0
gamma_best=0
for gamma in gammas:
    for C in Cs:
        svm=SVC(gamma=gamma,C=C)
        svm.fit(X_train,y_train)
        score=svm.score(X_valid,y_valid)
        if score>best_score:
            best_score=score
            C_best=C
            gamma_best=gamma
```

and I evaluate the best parameters on test set as follows:

```
svm=SVC(gamma=gamma_best,C=C_best)
svm.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Score on test set for best C=%0.3f and best gamma=%0.3f is %0.3f"%(C_best,gamma_best,svm.score(X_test,y_test)))
```

and I get an 82% accuracy.

If I perform a 5-Fold Cross Validation as follows:

```
X_folds = np.array_split(X, 5)
y_folds = np.array_split(y, 5)
scores = list()
for gamma in gammas:
   for C in Cs:
       for k in range(5):
           svm=SVC(gamma=gamma,C=C)
           X_train = list(X_folds)
           X_test = X_train.pop(k)
           X_train = np.concatenate(X_train)
           y_train = list(y_folds)
           y_test = y_train.pop(k)
           y_train = np.concatenate(y_train)
           scores.append(svm.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test))
           score=np.mean(scores)
           if score>best_score:
              best_score=score
              C_best=C
              gamma_best=gamma
svm=SVC(C=C_best,gamma=gamma_best)
svm.fit(X_trainval,y_trainval)
print("The score on test set is %0.3f"%(svm.score(X_test,y_test)))
```

I get an 80% accuracy, i.e. a lower accuracy. Why? Thank you in advance

Answer (score -5):

Model fits overestimate accuracy because the total uncertainty is not taken into account.  That is the reason for doing cross-validation in the first place. So the cross-validated estimate of accuracy is more honest in the sense that it does not contain the bias introduced by the fit.

Comment: (-1) Please read questions carefully. The OP is asking why the cross-validated estimate of accuracy is lower than that on *an independent test set*.

Comment: @Scortchi I think you misunderstood my answer.  I said that "Model fits overestimate accuracy" meaning that without cross-validation the estimated accuracy will tend to be too high.  So cross-validation gives a lower and more honest estimate of accuracy.  Isn't that exactly what the OP asked for?

Comment: @Scotchi Don't you noiw see that the downvote you gave to me was not deserved?

Comment: Fitting induces a bias on the training set, the data on which the model is fit. The OP is evaluating the performance of their model on a test set separated out before the model was fit on the remaining data.

Comment: You lost me with that comment.

Comment: Sorry, probably because I wrote "data" instead of "model" in one place - now fixed.